# How to update HTML text using an XML document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I have some boxes which need to display images of movies and a small box under each box which needs to display the name of the movie. (see image links below)

I am required to create a feature which allows the user to update an image and text box with a new movie image and name of the movie using an XML file and the path to the image.

Can someone explain to me how all of this works? I am very new to web development and this doesn't make any sense to me.

Many thanks,

Farid

[image: Application Interface]

[image: XML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a rough and **untested** sketch of how you can do it.

1. Read the XML data from a file (let's say file.xml) using AJAX.

   ```
   window.onload = function () {
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
               buildHTML(xhttp);
           }
       };
       xhttp.open('GET', 'file.xml', true);
       xhttp.send();
   };
   ```
2. Loop through the XML data and build your HTML. This code *should* display a set of images and text.

   ```
   function buildHTML(xml) {
       var i;
       var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
       var programmes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Programme');
       var html = '';
       // loop through Programme elements
       for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) { 
           // build the HTML for the image and name text
           html += '<img src="' + programmes[i].getElementsByTagName('imagepath')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '">';
           html += "<span>" + programmes[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</span>';       
       }
       // 
       document.body.appendChild(html);
   }
   ```
3. Style your HTML using CSS.
4. Et voila.

FYI I built my example based off this [AJAX XML example on w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlfile.asp).